# Unable to use equal operator in where clause on `queryid` from `pg_stat_statements`

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

When analyzing an issue on a PostgreSQL 13 server we can successfully retrieve information querying from `pg_stat_statements`, but we are unable to retrieve a single record using a `queryid = -1234567600` in the where clause.

So this does not work:

```
-- given that queryid -1234567600 really exists
select query, queryid from pg_stat_statements where queryid = -1234567600;
```

But the strange thing is, this DOES work:

```
SELECT                                                                          
    queryid,                                                                    
    query                                       
FROM                                                                            
    pg_stat_statements                                                          
where
    queryid<=-1234567500
    and queryid >=-1234567700;
```

I was under the impression that the former should also work. Am I misunderstanding things?

Thanks!

Comment: It may be beneficial to provide the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi @BrendanMcCaffrey, there is no error. There is just no output. I think there is a overrun somewhere because on other databases (smaller than this one) there are no  negative numbers for queryid. And positive numbers for queryid work just fine.